# I’m an iOS developer and want to learn Ionic 2, what should I do first?

Tags: ionic2

I'm an iOS developer who have been using objective-c for two years.

Now situation is that I should build a shopping mall app in three months and it should be a hybrid app.

I googled for a while and everything tell me that Ionic 2 is the way I should go.

Problem is that I know nothing about JS, AngularJS, and node.js.
I know basic HTML and CSS.

Here's my plan.

1. Learn basic JS(ES6 or Typescript?) for half month.
2. Learn AngularJS for half month.
3. Learn node.js for half month.
4. Build app for one and half month.

The app I should make is not very complicated and not a huge project either.
If I build the app with native iOS code, it will take about a month.

My question is

1. Do you guys think the above plan is realizable?
2. If my plan looks wrong, then where should I start from?

I hope somebody who has similar background as mine would guide me, however, anyone please advice me.

Comment: First thing is to read the [help]. This question is off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't a programming path advice site.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I also think this is off-topic but you know, a drowning man will catch at a straw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is a tough question to answer, since it might be very individual.

You will certainly need to learn and gain some HTML and CSS skills since they define the way your app will look like.
However, Ionic 2 is based on Angular 2 which uses TypeScript as the main "language".
I added "" since TypeScript is a type-based language, which is actually very similar to Java or other OOP languages in it's syntax, and is transpiled into javascript.

In my opinion, in contrary to Angular 1.x, Angular 2 is much easier to learn and implement. The official tutorial is great.
The main disadventage though is that it is a pretty new platform (and the community is relatively small but growing).
Altough it is based on TypeScript, I do advice you to gain some basic JS skills, since you might find yourself need them at some point.

Regarding node.js - choosing Ionic as your front-end technlogy does not restrict you to work with JS based server-side platform.
It is a pretty quick platform to implement and learn, but if you are familiar with other server-side platforms you are free to work with them, since Angular 2 consumes RESTful services.

I would deffinetly start from playing around with Angular 2.0, only when you feel comfortable enough, you can move to Ionic.